# Property '$store' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance' using Vuex 4 with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuex

I have a project where I am using typescript and vue with vuex, I am having this error on  VSCode:

```
Property '$store' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, { errors(): any; }, { eliminarError(error: string): void; }, EmitsOptions, {}, {}, false, ComponentOptionsBase<{}, {}, {}, { errors(): any; }, { eliminarError(error: string): void; }, ... 4 more ..., {}>>'
```

I read [the documentation](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html) and there it says I have to add a d.ts file with this content:

```js
// vuex.d.ts
import { ComponentCustomProperties } from 'vue'
import { Store } from 'vuex'

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  // declare your own store states
  interface State {
    count: number
  }

  // provide typings for `this.$store`
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: Store<State>
  }
}
```

But then VSCode complains than `'ComponentCustomProperties' is defined but never used`, and it is still show the first error I mentioned

How can I solve this issues?

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this error on VSCode and it was resolved.

```js
// vuex.d.ts
import { ComponentCustomProperties } from 'vue'
import { Store } from 'vuex'

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  // declare your own store states
  interface State {
    count: number
  }

  // provide typings for `this.$store`
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: Store<State>
  }
}
```

**The configuration according to the official document did not take effect. After restarting VSCode, it finally took effect.**

Answer (score -1):

add `/* eslint-disable */` to the top of the shims-vuex.d.ts file